# How can I add only related products?

Tags: plugins

I want to seperate tabs and related products, so I used:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
```

This code worked well, but i want to add related products again to the single product page.

How can I add related products only?

Thank you.

Comment: Please take your time, use the WYSIWYG editor buttons to format code, use proper upper- and lowercase characters, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the action from it's hook, then add it to a different hook (corresponding to where you'd like it to display).  You can view the available hooks by viewing the WooCommerce `single-product.php` and `content-single-product.php` template files.  Just like it *all* of WordPress anywhere there is a `do_action( 'some_hook_name' )` that signifies an action hook that you can attach functions to.  Here is an example (for your `functions.php`) that will move the related products output to outside the #product div.

```
function wpa_115808(){
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
   add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'woocommerce_output_related_products' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'wpa_115808' );
```